# An OCaml function for finding fixed points

Tags: recursion, ocaml, fixed-point-iteration

I have an OCaml function for finding fixed points:

```
>> let rec fix f x =
     let x' = f x in
       if x = x' then x else fix f x';;
(system message) val fix : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

The question is, I don't understand how it works when I type:

```
>> let cubed x = x*x*x;;
(system message) val cubed : int -> int = <fun>

>> fix cubed 2;;
(system message) - : int = 0
```

In my understanding, `fix cubed 2` will go into an infinite loop of `fix cubed 2*2*2`, `fix cubed (2*2*2)*(2*2*2)*(2*2*2)` and so on. How does this function correctly finds the fixed point `0`?

Comment: The value probably overflows and at some point hits 0. Try entering for example `max_int + 1` or `max_int * max_int` in the repl to see it happening. This works the same across pretty much all programming languages with native integer data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less by accident.

What is happening is that you are using `cubed` on a power of two, which results in a larger power of two. After a few rounds of this the result will be large enough to overflow and be truncated - and large powers of two will truncate to zero, which happens to be a fixpoint of this function.

To be completely clear, OCaml will not do any kind of sophisticated search or trickery, `fix` is just a loop which happens to terminate with a useful answer in this case.

You can use `#trace` in the toplevel to see it happening:

```
# #trace cubed;;
cubed is now traced.
# fix cubed 2
  ;;
  cubed <-- 2
cubed --> 8
cubed <-- 8
cubed --> 512
cubed <-- 512
cubed --> 134217728
cubed <-- 134217728
cubed --> 0
cubed <-- 0
cubed --> 0
- : int = 0
```